# How to RSpec API based Ruby on Rails application (No database)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

1.My Ruby on Rails application doesn't have a database.

2.All functionalities even login is done by requesting user through API call.
For example to authenticate user I need the following Api call.

```
Api::User.verify_password("username", "password")
```

How do I write RSpec test cases to cover all features?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two things:

- don't test the api from your app
- stub all api calls to focus on your business logic

Example:

```
 Api::User.stub(:verify_password).and_return your_json_or_xml
```